# When adding entity the EntityFramework wants to create instead of reference related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I have DDD entities as below:

```
public class Grant
{
    public string GrantId { get; set; }
    // Other properties omitted
}

public class AuthorizationCode
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public Grant? Grant { get; set; }
    // Other properties omitted
}
```

And that's code to add the entity:

```
public async Task StoreAsync(AuthorizationCode authorizationCode, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    await _dbContext.AddAsync(authorizationCode, cancellationToken);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

When adding the new `AuthorizationCode` then EntityFramework instead of referencing existing `Grant`, it wants to create new and I get exception:

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Grants'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Grants'. The duplicate key value is (1l7xVpoEEhgHmZVZf28PvpO3lGg_xV59H69LCB4lPkQ). The statement has been terminated.

`Grant` configuration:

```
public class GrantConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Grant>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Grant> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(p => p.GrantId);
    }
}
```

`AuthorizationCode` configuration:

```
public class AuthorizationCodeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AuthorizationCode>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AuthorizationCode> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(p => p.Code);
    }
}
```

The `Grant` is created before `AuthorizationCode`, at different HTTP endpoint. The relations in database are valid. So what's wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide the code that is doing the update or the insert?

Comment: I edited my question and added it. I don't update this entity

Comment: Use `Update` instead of `AddAsync`. This is a very common issue. BTW the async version of `Add` should only be used in special cases, please see the docs.

Comment: I do `_dbContext.Attach`, then `Update` and `SaveChangesAsync`.  But I get `DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded`. Btw this appropach seems strange to me - could you explain why `Update` instead of `AddAsync`?

Comment: First of all, `AddAsync` isn't needed unless you use a strange key generator like HiLo. `Add` will attach the detached (ie created in memory, not loaded from DB) object and *all other reachable objects* in the `Added` state. If the new object already existed, you'd need to attach in the `Modified` state. That's what` Updated` does. `Update` is smarter than that though, and will attach in the `Added` state if the object has no PK values (eg a long ID of 0). Neither `Add` nor `Update` talk to the database though. They do what the docs say - they attach objects in the specified state

Comment: If you *don't* know whether the data exists in the database you *have* to check. `SaveChanges` won't generate a check to select INSERT or UPDATE. Most of the time though you *should* know whether the objects exist or not, eg because you loaded them yourself, or they were the payload of a PUT or DELETE. You really need to explain what scenario results in objects with unknown state

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new GrantConfiguration());
modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new AuthorizationCodeConfiguration());
```

in `OnModelCreating` method of your context.