# How to get all properties of instance of EF entity that are used to build relation

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-core

I have to write generic repository, so also method to add entities. The problem is with entities that have relationships to existing entities - they must be tracked.

So I have to write some code that will recognize which properties of some entity are used to built relationship and attach them.

How? I thought about something like that:

```
public async Task StoreAsync(TEntity model, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    foreach (var prop in model.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetType().IsClass))
    {
        var related = prop.GetValue(model)!;
        if (_dbContext.Entry(related).State == EntityState.Detached)
            _dbContext.Attach(prop.GetValue(model));
    }

    await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().AddAsync(model, cancellationToken);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

But there are multiple problems with this code - firstly, we get properties that are not value types, so `record`, `delegate` and `class`. Delegates and records cannot be entities.

And another (im not sure if this is problem) thing is that we attach all detached entities. But what if some entity currently doesnt exist in database? What if we attach non-exsiting and will use it like existing?

So how to get all properties of instance of EF entity that are used to build relation?

*I use NET7*

Comment: What you try to do is what `.Add` does automatically. The code is buggy though - `AddAsync` doesn't add anything and *is **not*** required for autogenerated values. It's there only for value generators like HiLo that require info from the database before calculating a value. `SaveChanges` saves *all* pending changes, including DELETE or UPSERT, not just the last Add. Your code can easily perform 2 DELETEs. Calling SaveChanges multiple times means you now need an explicit transaction to roll back changes

Comment: You can delete the entire function and just call [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.add?view=efcore-7.0). As the docs say: `Begins tracking the given entity, and any other reachable entities that are not already being tracked, in the Added state`. *Don't* call `SaveChanges` immediately. Wait until the last moment to persist all changes. `SaveChanges` uses an internal transaction. The DbContext instance is an entire Unit-of-Work. If you want to "rollback", just don't call `SaveChanges` and let the context get disposed

Comment: `I have to write generic repository` quite the opposite. The DbContext and DbSet are *already* high-level Unit-of-Work and Repository implementations. The CRUD interfaces and classes found in various articles are low-level Data Access Objects, not repositories. Putting a low level "repository" over a high level Unit of Work is a bug. [Repositories and Unit of Work don't mix](https://robconery.com/databases/repositories-on-top-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/) , [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/)

Comment: 1. Yes, it seems fine, but I use DDD. I can't assume that Infrastructure layer uses EF and I can use DbContext immediately. That's why I need layer of abstraction (repository) that later is implemented using EF. 2. It adds untracked entities into Added state, but sometimes I have scenario where entity is not tracked but exists in database.

Comment: And DDD talks about domain repositories, not low-level DAOs. DDD isn't the IRepository CRUD. `I can't assume that Infrastructure layer uses EF` but that's exactly what you're doing right now, tightly coupling yourself to a *bad* implementation. What are you trying to abstract anyway? Have you thought about this or following a "prescription"? If you want to reimpose CRUD, why use EF **at all**? You're trying to remove all the abstractions, replace them with almost direct database operations

Comment: `sometimes I have scenario where entity is not tracked but exists in database.` that's the job of `Update`. `Update` will attach an entity in the `Added` state if its PK has a default value, or `Modified` if it has a non-default value

Comment: What are you trying to abstract with this CRUD class? It's not access to a relational database. That's what ORMs like EF do. Extra classes should *raise* the level of abstraction, not lower it. Above EF you can either a multi-class domain repository or a service. Are you to allow moving to a columnar or document database? The differences will be so big that the *common* part will be the domain repository, not the CRUD functions.

Comment: A document database like Mongo returns an entire graph as a document, not individual objects. EF also retrieves an entire graph of objects and any related objects. ORMs try to give the impression of working with in-memory objects, not database rows that need to be CRUDed. Where would you put an abstraction that handles both Mongo and EF? And what would it look like?

Comment: Then there's the concurrency model that's getting violated for *both* EF and document databases. Both use optimistic concurrency but a CRUD interface *demands* pessimistic concurrency with explicit transactions. That's bad from a DDD and performance perspective. The concurrency details now leak to the very top. As for performance, you're going all the way back to the 1990s, as long-running transactions start blocking each other.

Comment: Long story short, you don't need any of that code, just `_dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(model)`. If you insist, you can keep `SaveChangesAsync` in there at the cost of violating DDD and harming isolation, concurrency, consistency and performance

Comment: 1. I said that `I can't assume that Infrastrucutre layer uses EF` and that's true. The code I provided is just implementation of some repository using EF. But I can have another data access layer that uses e.g. Dapper. I know it seems strange but these are requirements of the project. 2. So when to call `SaveChangesAsync`? While disposing `DbContext`, in destructor? Or maybe while disposing repository? 3. My entities primary keys are strings generated in code. So `Update` will always mark entity as Modified, even if the entity doesnt exist.

Comment: No, it doesn't seem strange. I do that myself. And I have no CRUD classes, because the queries I run are specific. If I wanted to just insert objects, I'd use EF as-is. I use Dapper for more complex queries (eg reporting, batch updates) that aren't CRUD. Bulk imports? That's SqlBulkCopy, again not CRUD.

Comment: What you try to do is the opposite of abstracting the data API though. Instead of *raising* the abstraction of both EF and Dapper to the same level, you try to *lower* EF to Dapper's level. Why do you even use EF if you don't want the higher level features, like Unit-of-Work, automatic relation and change tracking, reference  fixup, mappings etc?

Comment: 1. In most cases I don't need change tracking, but there are exceptions where I need to update something and then I need to track related entity (and that's problem I mentioned in question). And because most scenarios don't use tracking, I just dont use it for performance. 2. My repository allow to use complex queries by using `Expression`.

Comment: So you use EF Core as a query builder. Why not use a query builder library with Dapper? Did you read the links I posted? (Add [Repository is the new Singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) to the list).  This isn't some new debate. All the contradictions and conflicts inherent in what you're trying to do have been found and discussed over and over. Some go back 20 years. DDD doesn't prescribe CRUD DAOs, that's how some *authors* tried to describe domain repositories because they couldn't include EF/ORMs in their books

Comment: The fact remains that you don't need reflection. `Add` already does what you want, *especially* if the PK isn't database-generated. Just `_dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(model);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);` will store the object *and all other pending changes*

Comment: I believe that just `Add` is not enough. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76438480/when-adding-entity-the-entityframework-wants-to-create-instead-of-reference-rela The problem was that related entity wasn't tracked, so I just assumed that it exists and manually attached related entities to context. It worked. But I did it to fix problem quickly. In reality, I don't want to write different `StoreAsync` method for every entity and update the code every time I add new relation to entity (I mean relation to new table).

Comment: It's enough. You don't have to write anything. The code is wrong. You tried to Add something that was already added. Do you know whether the object exists or not? If *not*, you need to check, which is a problem with how EF is used

Comment: You think that if I replace `AddAsync` with `Add`, then will it work?

Comment: I think you misuse EF. It's not `AddAsync`, that's a recent addition meant to handle HiLo. Either you know whether the object exists or not. If not, you *must* check if it does. By generating the key in memory, you lose the easy way of checking. In ASP.NET Core, you know whether it exists or not from the HTTP action (POST, PUT, DELETE) so you can use `Add` or `Update` accordingly. None of these requires writing extra code. All DbContext/LINQ operations are generic

Comment: If you want to allow eg POST/PUT to both insert and modify data, you'd have to try to load the existing object with, eg `Find(pk_value)`, apply any changes to it (AutoMapper can do that based on naming conventions or configuration) and then just store it. No need for `Update`, the object will already be in the `Modified` state